# Detect when a key is pressed and then released using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, jquery-events

I would like to check, using jQuery, when a key is pressed and then released. Only after the release do I want the function to be run (it's okay if the only way to do this doesn't involve jQuery, but if there's a way for both I'd rather it be the one with fewer bytes).
I'm pretty sure that the solution would use a mix of `keyup()` and `keydown()`, or `keypress()` functions, but I haven't figured out how to chain them so that the code would receive the desired output. My current code is:

```
$("body").keydown(function(event) {
    $("body").keyup(function(event) {
        console.log("key pressed/released");
        var keyPressed = keys[event.keyCode];
        player.hit(keyPressed);
    });
});
```

But that results in tens of `key pressed/released` messages being logged in the console after I release a key. Taking away either `keydown()` or `keyup()` results in `key pressed/released` messages being logged when I hit a key, or when I release it, respectively. `keypress()` also doesn't work in place of `keydown()`, `keyup()`, or just by itself. What should I do to acheive my desired result?

Comment: I have to strongly recommend you use [Mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice)

Comment: *"the one with fewer bytes"* - Do you mean other than the jQuery.js file itself? So, say, three lines of code calling jQuery methods plus the whole jQuery.js library would be "fewer" than ten lines of non-jQuery code?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, I mean in my file itself. It doesn't really matter, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can create a variable, say x. x is false. Separate the keyup and keydown functions. under keydown add an if(!x) and make x true. Under keyup add an if(x) and make x false.
I don't code jquery but I thought this might help.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to check, using jQuery, when a key is pressed and then released.
>   Only after the release do I want the function to be run

Well, if `keyup` is fired, you can be sure the key was both pressed and released, otherwise that event wouldn't fire, so that's really all you need.

```
$(document).on('keyup', function() {
    console.log('key was released')
})
```

or without jQuery

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    console.log('key was released')
});
```

The reason your code ends up logging tens, and then hundreds of messages, is because you bind events inside event handlers, which is a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to separate out the two functions, then make use of a variable accessible to both functions.

Start by stating that no key is pressed. Inside your `keydown()`, run a conditional that checks whether or not a key is currently being pressed. By setting the `key_pressed` variable to `true` inside of the conditional, you'll only trigger the conditional once; when the key is **first** pressed.

Then when the key is released, set the variable back to `false` to state that no keys are currently being pressed. This will allow you to press a secondary key after releasing the first key, and trigger the conditional again:

```js
var key_pressed = false;

$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  if (!key_pressed) {
    console.log("key pressed");
    key_pressed = true;
  };
});

$("body").keyup(function(event) {
  key_pressed = false;
  console.log('key released');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that you're able to trigger logic specifically while the key is being held down.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you got ninja'd by @Confused Soul, but thanks for adding the code and the code snippet.

Comment: Haha yeah, he was certainly very fast to the post! He was indeed first (with the appropriate answer), so I can't really complain about you accepting his answer over mine :) However, note that although you can't accept two answers, you **can** change the choice of a selected answer (or even 'unaccept' an answer entirely) if you feel that one is better. Plus once you reach 15 reputation, you'll be able to [**up-vote**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) any answer to indicate that it is helpful -- it doesn't need to be the accepted one :)

Comment: Yep, I once had 31 Karma, but my account got banned from asking questions.